# Dynamically get property from select function using variable

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to dynamically get all the values of a specific property from all class instances. I've managed to do it with one property

```
public class fighter
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public double Height { get; set; }
    }

fighter[] roster[5] = new fighter();

string namearray = roster.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
int weightarray = roster.Select(x => x.Weight).ToArray();
```

However I want to reference the property with a variable and put it in a loop so I don't need a select function for every property. Is there anyway to do this, or any other method to get all values of a property from all objects where this could work?

Comment: Most of this code wont compile, also `foreach(var fighter in roster)`  maybe what you are looking for, however its hard to tell

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense either.

Comment: Also not sure why you have tagged `reflection`?

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        stud stud = new stud() { id=10,name="test" };
        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo;
        propertyInfo = typeof(stud).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var item in propertyInfo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " : " + item.GetValue(stud));
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class stud {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

use following code, i have created a propertyInfo class from System.Reflection namespace which allows to get property names of the class. after which once you get all the names of properties can be accessed using propertyinfo.GetValue function.